# Generating toString with ant using wsimport - ServiceConfigurationError

Tags: java, ant, jax-ws, xjc, wsimport

I'm using wsimport task to generate classes from .wsdl and I wanted to generate toString method along with it. I'm using the code:

```
<target name="wsimport_v2">
    <taskdef name="wsimport" classname="com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="C:\Users\a\Documents\Antin\antifun\lib\jaxws-tools.jar" />
            <pathelement location="C:\Users\a\Documents\Antin\antifun\lib\jaxb2-basics-0.6.0.jar" />
            <pathelement location="C:\Users\a\Documents\Antin\antifun\lib\jaxb2-basics-tools-0.6.0.jar" />
            <pathelement location="C:\Users\a\Documents\Antin\antifun\lib\jaxb2-basics-ant-0.6.0.jar" />
            <pathelement location="C:\Users\a\Documents\Antin\antifun\lib\jaxb2-basics-runtime-0.6.0.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
    <mkdir dir="/tmp" />
    <wsimport wsdl="/src/wsdl/WebSubscriptionService_v_4.3.wsdl" destdir="/tmp" sourcedestdir="C:\Users\a\Documents\Antin\antifun\src\antifun\generated" keep="true" xnocompile="true">
        <xjcArg value="-XtoString"/>
    </wsimport>
</target>
```

But I'm getting

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\a584187\Documents\Antin\antifun\build.xml
wsimport_v2:
[wsimport] Consider using <depends>/<produces> so that wsimport won't do unnecessary compilation

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\a584187\Documents\Antin\antifun\build.xml:13:     java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.tools.xjc.Plugin: Provider     org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.plugin.tostring.ToStringPlugin could not be instantiated

Total time: 737 milliseconds
```